# Android Studio error: Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

Tags: android, android-studio, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am developing an Android app for Emotion recognition using Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services. I am using the code from the following GitHub repository.

**https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Emotion-Android**

When I run the application on Asus smartphone with Android 8, I get the following error:

Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

I have tried adding the following in build.gradle(Module:app) inside android block

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

This does not solve the issue.

These are the dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:1.0.355'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You're using a C library that you haven't included a .so for in the correct ABI for that phone.  Which is most likely armv7, but without the exact model we can't tell.  Make sure you have so files for all your abis, and it matches the abi of your device.

Comment: I checked the ABI on my phone by using this code. Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS[0]. It is arm64-v8a. Even after including it, I am getting the same error

Comment: splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a','x86_64', 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }